# Catel DataWindow OK buttom hotkey and focus

Tags: catel

1. How can I assign a hotkey (F10) to Catel DataWindow OK button?
2. How can I focus programmaticaly (from code behind) the Catel DataWindow's OK button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataWindowMode.Custom and put your own buttons in there. Then you have all the freedom you need.